# EventHandler PercentComplete on class to update ProgressBar

Tags: c#

I need to update my progressbar with `EventHandler` by a Class, but in the same form. How can i do that? Background work it's a way? I have tried to pass the progressbar parameter, but won't work.

```
class GenerateBackup()
void Backup()
{
   Backup bkp = new Backup(){..}
   bkp.PercentComplete += bkp_PercentComplete;
   bkp.Complete += bkp_Complete;
}

private void bkp_Complete (Label Status, object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Status.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Status.Text = e.Error.Message;
        });
    }
}

private void bkp_PercentComplete(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    barraProgresso.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        barraProgresso.Value = e.Percent;
        barraProgresso.Update();
    });

    lblPercentual.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        lblPercentual.Text = e.Percent.ToString() + "%";
    });
}
```

If I try to pass the progressbar as param, it doesn't work, and I get delegate errors.

Comment: "didn't work" and "got errors" is next to useless for us. How didn't it work? What were the errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to use BackgroundWorker in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153258/1838048)

Comment: new Backup(){..} cannot work, you must refer to the control on the form.  Pass the reference as an argument.  Fwiw, Winforms is relentlessly OOPy, you do prefer this code inside the Form class until you get up to speed.